# crypt :basename in a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using paperclip and asigning the path url in the following way

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/:basename.:extension"
```

the problem is that I need to crypt the basename attribute, okey rails has a function crypt but how can I use it into the route, something like this:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/#{:basename.crypt('key')}.:extension"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606804/paperclip-how-to-change-basename-filename

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/test/interpolations_test.rb

Answer (score 0):

see if this works

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/#{Paperclip::Interpolations.basename.crypt('key')}.:extension"
```

Comment: didn't work cuz basename Interpolation receives two params attachment and style....